# Create a polyfill for HTML5 Validation

Tags: javascript, html, polyfills

I'm building a very simple Validation plugin that uses part of the Constraint validation API. I'm using 2 features of the API, valueMissing and patternMismatch like so:

```
var el = $(this)[0];

if ( el.validity.valueMissing || el.validity.patternMismatch )  {
        $errMsg.show();
} else {
        $errMsg.hide();
}
```

I'd like to write my own polyfill so these features work in older browsers as opposed to using an entire HTML5 validation library or plugin.

So I guess what I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
if (!typeof document.createElement( 'input' ).checkValidity == 'function'){
    validity.valueMissing = function(){
        // check for value
    }
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to go about this, nor how the element is used as the first part of the function:

```
el.validity.valueMissing
```

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: what type of object is `el` from the first example ?

Comment: It's a JavaScript DOM element: var el = $(this)[0];

Answer (score 2):

There would be a bit of work involved for this poly, but what you need to do, is alter `HTMLInputElement`'s prototype, so each new instance has those methods and propertyes (`validity`, `checkValidity` and so on).

Something along these lines:

```
HTMLInputElement.prototype.testMethod = function (e) { console.log(e) };
HTMLInputElement.prototype.testProp = 'foo';
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.testMethod(input.testProp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Poelinca. This certainly pointed me in the right direction, so +1 for your answer. However, I cannot mark as correct as it's not the complete answer

Answer (score 1):

So I finally figured this out with some help from Poelinca's answer...

```
if ( typeof document.createElement( 'input' ).checkValidity !== 'function' ) {
    Object.defineProperty( Element.prototype, 'validity', {
        get: function() {
            return this;
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty( Element.prototype.validity, 'valueMissing', {
        get: function() {
            return this.value !== "";
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty( Element.prototype.validity, 'patternMismatch', {
        get: function() {
            var pattern = this.getAttribute('pattern'),
                regEx = pattern !== null ? eval( "{/" + pattern + "/}" ) : "";
                value = this.value;

            if ( regEx !== "" ) {
                return regEx.test( value );
            } else {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I used Object.defineProperty so I could call the function without using the parenthesis, which is how the native Constraint validation API works:

```
if ( el.validity.valueMissing || el.validity.patternMismatch )  { //...
```

From my research I learned that extending the DOM like this isn't really recommended as you can run into a lot of issues. For details read [this article](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/). The comments are particularly helpful as this article is quite dated.

In my case what I'm trying to do is quite simple and I only need to support IE8+. Maybe a little overkill but I like it.

Please feel free to improve / critique my answer!

Thanks!